# Error propagation for the mean of time-series

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, statistics

From what I have read, when measure repeatedly the same quantity **X** N times and the measurements follow a normal distribution the uncertainty of the mean is $σ_{mean} = \frac{σ}{\sqrt{N}}$ where σ is the standard deviation of the measurements.

Now let's assume that we don't measure the same thing all the time, but we have got a set of different measurements without autocorrelation of a parameter **P** that changes with time for a time period **t**. The question is how do we calculate the uncertainty propagated to **mean** value of the period **t** from the uncertainties of the measurements.

1. If each measurement has the **same** uncertainty **u** (random error) and the dataset follows a normal distribution would that be correct to use  $u_{mean} = \frac{u}{\sqrt{N}}$ ?
2. If each measurement has a **different** uncertainty $u_{i}$  would that be correct to use the same formula like this: $u_{mean} = \frac{(1/Ν)\sqrt{\sum{u_i^2}}}{\sqrt{N}}$ ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have different measurements for a random variable and wish to combine these measurements for an overall estimate of the variable and its uncertainty.  If this is what you want, see my answer to [Uncertainty in repetitive measurements](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459184/uncertainty-in-repetitive-measurements) on this exchange.

If you are after something different, please clarify and let me know and I will respond.