# Uncertainty formula for division

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

$$(A \pm a) \times (B \pm b)=AB\left(1 \pm \frac aA \pm \frac bB\right)$$

Here is the formula im struggling with, I'm just trying to apply this formula for division (i.e for speed, $\frac dt$, instead of momentum $mv$). How would I apply this formula for when $B = \frac 1B$ ? I have discovered that if you were to change AB to $\frac AB$, and remain $a$ and $b$ as if you were to use the formula to multiply $AB$ instead of $\frac AB$, you'd arrive at the correct solution. But, wouldn't you have to use the uncertainty of $B$ in the form of $\frac 1B$ – which I don't know how to find ?

Answer (score 6):

In both multiplication and division, it is the fractional uncertainties which add in quadrature. That is,

\begin{align}
(A±a)×(B±b)
&=AB×\left(
1±\frac aA
\right) \left(
1±\frac bB
\right)
\end{align}

From the binomial theorem you can say

$$
\left(
B+b
\right)^{-n}
≈
B^{-n}\left(
1-n\frac bB
\right)
$$

So if for instance you have fractional uncertainty $b/B≈1\%$, the inverse $C=B^{-1}$ will also have fractional uncertainty $1\%$. This is also the origin of the rule for propagating uncertainties through other exponents.

Comment: +1. This is so important that it bears repeating: addition and subtraction propagate *absolute* errors, while multiplication and division propagate *relative* errors.

Comment: Where did you get the binomial expression from?

Comment: @Yao From a professor in my sophomore year, who said, “this trick isn’t on our syllabus, but it’s impossibly useful.” See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation

Answer (score 6):

The binomial theorem, as rob explains, gives a powerful method for propagating uncertainties through any power of a quantity. However, if if the power is just –1, here's a simple trick...
$$(B+b)(B-b) = B^2-b^2$$
But if $b\ll B$ then $b^2 \lll B^2$, so we neglect $b^2$ and divide through by $B^2$ giving
$$\left(1+\tfrac bB\right)\left(1-\tfrac bB\right)=1$$
That is
$$\left(1+\tfrac bB\right)^{-1}=\left(1-\tfrac bB\right)$$
So the fractional uncertainty in $B^{-1}$ is the same as that in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the product rule for differentiation and assume that the errors are small to find the fractional change.

$\Delta (A\cdot B) \approx \Delta A \cdot B + A\cdot \Delta B \,\Rightarrow \,\dfrac{\Delta (A\cdot B)}{A\cdot B} \approx \dfrac{\Delta A}{A} + \dfrac{\Delta B}{B}$

You can also do the same method for the quotient $A/B$ to get the result $\dfrac{\Delta (A/B)}{A/B} \approx \dfrac{\Delta A}{A} + \dfrac{\Delta B}{B}$ and then to power relationships eg $\dfrac {\Delta A^n}{A^n}\approx n \dfrac {\Delta A}{A}$

Note that these are overestimates of the error and a better estimator of the error in both cases is $\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\Delta A}{A}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\Delta B}{B}\right )^2}$

Comment: A nice variation ... If $Q=\frac AB$ then $\ln Q =\ln A-\ln B$, so for small changes $$\frac{\Delta Q}Q=\frac{\Delta A}A-\frac{\Delta B}B$$ So, assuming the worst case of uncs in $A$ and $B$ being in opposite directions, we add the moduli of the fractional uncs.

Comment: A@PhilipWood  Nice but what about the minus sign?

Comment: I posted prematurely (pressed 'return' to start a new line). 'Durrr', you might say.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(X,Y)$ be a function of two random variables $X$ and $Y$.  Let $X_m$ be the mean of $X$ and $S_X$ the standard deviation of $X$.  Let $Y_m$ be the mean of $Y$ and $S_Y$ the standard deviation of $Y$. The mean of $f(X, Y)$ is $ f_m = f(X_m, Y_m)$. Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, retaining the lower order terms in a series expansion of $f(X,Y)$ about the point $P = (X_m, Y_m)$, the variance of $f(X, Y)$, denoted as $S_f^2$ where $S_f$ is the standard deviation, is

$(1) \enspace S_f^2 = ({\partial f \over \partial X}|_P)^2\, S_X^2 + ({\partial f \over \partial Y}|_P)^2\, S_Y^2 + ({\partial ^2f \over \partial X \partial Y}|_P)^2 \,S_X^2\,S_Y^2$

If both $X_m$ and $Y_m$ are not zero, the variance can be approximated as

$(2) \enspace S_f^2 = ({\partial f \over \partial X}|_P)^2\, S_X^2 + ({\partial f \over \partial Y}|_P)^2\, S_Y^2$

It appears you want to estimate the uncertainty in $A/B$ for random variables $A$ and $B$ given uncertainties in $A$ and $B$. You have $A_m \pm a$ where $A_m$ is the mean of A and $a$ is the standard deviation of $A$, and $B_m \pm b$ where $B_m$ is the mean of B and $b$ is the standard deviation of $B$. For this case $B_M$ cannot be zero.

The mean for $A/B$ is $A_m/ B_m$. Assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent, you can use the above relationships to estimate the standard deviation for $f(A, B) = A/B$.

For example, suppose $A_m \pm a = 5.2 \pm 0.9$ and  $B_m \pm b = 3.4 \pm 0.2$ The mean of $A/B$ is $5.2/3.4 = 1.53$. Using relationship (2), the standard deviation of $A/B$ is $(3) \enspace S_{A/B} =\sqrt{{1 \over B_M^{\,2}} a^2 + {A_M^{\,2} \over B_M^{\,4}} b^2} = 0.28$, where $S_{A/B}$ is the standard deviation of $A/B$.
Relationship (3) can also be expressed as $(4) \enspace{S_{A/B}^2 \over (A/B)_M^2} = {1 \over A_M^{\,2}} a^2 + {1 \over B_M^{\,2}} b^2$  where $(A/B)_M$ is the mean of $A/B$. The result for $A/B$ is $1.53 \pm 0.28$.

If $A$ and $B$ are not independent, you must retain covariant terms in the series expansion.  For details see Meyer, Data Analysis for Scientists and Engineers, or a similar textbook dealing with the propagation of uncertainty.

You need to determine if your means and standard deviations for $A$ and $B$ that you are using in $A_M \pm a$ and $B_m \pm b$ are estimates for the **population**, or are estimates for the **means** of the population generated from a series of random samples.  In either case the relationships (1) and (2) are correct but the data can represent different concepts.  For details see my response to [Uncertainty in repetitive measurements](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459184/uncertainty-in-repetitive-measurements) on this exchange.